# non promiscuous option in tcpdump

Tags: tcpdump

Strangely, depending on the program in which it is included, the `tcpdump` command used with the `-p` option (which should say "don't use promiscuous mode") nevertheless switches it on during the capture.

The help information for `tcpdump` indeed says that the `-p` option does not guarantee that promiscuous mode will not turn on "because there may be other reasons to switch it on".

What can be these reasons? How I can I find them in my program?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an example of an instance where you specify the `-p` option but `tcpdump` still puts the interface in promiscuous mode?

Comment: Use `apt-get source tcpdump` to see the Real Truth.